# create separate output files from single xslt based on condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I would appreciated if someone could help me to create xslt to create multiple outputs on the condition

Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
    <Meta>
        <GpsFile>notepad_may_30_file</GpsFile>
        <GpsId>36fa4fe8-9691-4a7f-8bc1-9543f6b7d29a</GpsId>
        <ExePath>
            <ExePath1>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\notepad.exe</ExePath1>
        </ExePath>
    </Meta>
    <Process>
        <GStep DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
                <Step-ID>3</Step-ID>     
                <Step-Exe>Notepad.exe</Step-Exe>     
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1 />      
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
                <Step-ID>4</Step-ID>     
                <Step-Exe>iexporer.exe</Step-Exe> 
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1 />     
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
                <Step-ID>5</Step-ID>   
                <Step-Exe>iexporer.exe</Step-Exe>             
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1>Edit</PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1>     
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
                <Step-ID>6</Step-ID>     
                <Step-Exe>Notepad.exe</Step-Exe>              
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1>Replace...\tCtrl+H</PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1>     
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
                <Step-ID>12</Step-ID>   
                <Step-Exe>iexporer.exe</Step-Exe>             
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1 />     
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
                <Step-ID>13</Step-ID>  
                <Step-Exe>Notepad.exe</Step-Exe>              
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1>Edit</PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1>      
            </Step>
        </GStep>
        <GStep DialogName="Replace">
            <Step DialogName="Replace">
                <Step-ID>8</Step-ID>    
                <Step-Exe>iexporer.exe</Step-Exe>               
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1 />      
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Replace">
                <Step-ID>9</Step-ID>      
                <Step-Exe>Notepad.exe</Step-Exe> 
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1>Cancel</PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1>     
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Replace">
                <Step-ID>10</Step-ID>  
                <Step-Exe>iexporer.exe</Step-Exe>               
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1 />     
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Replace">
                <Step-ID>16</Step-ID>   
                <Step-Exe>iexporer.exe</Step-Exe>               
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1 />     
            </Step>
        </GStep>
    </Process>
</Document>
```

Actually expecting a output files like below.

OUTPUT1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
    <Meta>
        <GpsFile>notepad_may_30_file</GpsFile>
        <GpsId>36fa4fe8-9691-4a7f-8bc1-9543f6b7d29a</GpsId>
        <ExePath>
            <ExePath1>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\notepad.exe</ExePath1>
        </ExePath>
    </Meta>
    <Process>
        <GStep DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
                <Step-ID>3</Step-ID>     
                <Step-Exe>Notepad.exe</Step-Exe>     
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1 />      
            </Step>         
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
                <Step-ID>6</Step-ID>     
                <Step-Exe>Notepad.exe</Step-Exe>              
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1>Replace...\tCtrl+H</PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1>     
            </Step>         
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
                <Step-ID>13</Step-ID>  
                <Step-Exe>Notepad.exe</Step-Exe>              
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1>Edit</PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1>      
            </Step>
        </GStep>
        <GStep DialogName="Replace">            
            <Step DialogName="Replace">
                <Step-ID>9</Step-ID>      
                <Step-Exe>Notepad.exe</Step-Exe> 
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1>Cancel</PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1>     
            </Step>
        </GStep>
    </Process>
</Document>
```

OUTPUT2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
    <Meta>
        <GpsFile>notepad_may_30_file</GpsFile>
        <GpsId>36fa4fe8-9691-4a7f-8bc1-9543f6b7d29a</GpsId>
        <ExePath>
            <ExePath1>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\notepad.exe</ExePath1>
        </ExePath>
    </Meta>
    <Process>
        <GStep DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">         
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
                <Step-ID>4</Step-ID>     
                <Step-Exe>iexporer.exe</Step-Exe> 
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1 />     
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
                <Step-ID>5</Step-ID>   
                <Step-Exe>iexporer.exe</Step-Exe>             
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1>Edit</PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1>     
            </Step>         
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
                <Step-ID>12</Step-ID>   
                <Step-Exe>iexporer.exe</Step-Exe>             
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1 />     
            </Step>         
        </GStep>
        <GStep DialogName="Replace">
            <Step DialogName="Replace">
                <Step-ID>8</Step-ID>    
                <Step-Exe>iexporer.exe</Step-Exe>               
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1 />      
            </Step>         
            <Step DialogName="Replace">
                <Step-ID>10</Step-ID>  
                <Step-Exe>iexporer.exe</Step-Exe>               
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1 />     
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Replace">
                <Step-ID>16</Step-ID>   
                <Step-Exe>iexporer.exe</Step-Exe>               
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName1 />     
            </Step>
        </GStep>
    </Process>
</Document>
```

Based on the   value it  creates a output files.

Example:Should create multiple output files depending upon th  values

```
<Step-Exe>Notepad.exe </Step-Exe>
<Step-Exe>Iexplorer.exe </Step-Exe>
<Step-Exe>winword.exe </Step-Exe>

**Mentioned about example should create 3 output files.**
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: In XSLT 1.0  a single transformation cannot produce multiple output files (unless your processor happens to support it as an extension). For the actual grouping see: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Is it possible in above version?

Comment: @Kreji: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-result-document